# Determine Number of Trailing Zeros of a Factorial Function (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function that returns the number of trailing zeros of a factorial. It seems that the amount of zeros increases from 0! for every 5 positive increments, but also increases 1 zero for every 25 increments. The problem is that when I pass in a number like 1000, it should return 249, but it returns 240 instead. Am I missing something?

I'm almost positive there is a better way to write this, but hopefully, someone can tell me what I'm missing in my current function?

*Note: This function must not calculate the actual factorial to determine the number of trailing zeros.*

```js
function zeros(n) {
  const extraZeros = n/25
  const zeros = n/5
  if(extraZeros >= 1) {
    return zeros + Math.floor(extraZeros)
  }else{
    return Math.floor(zeros)
  }
}
console.log(zeros(0), 0);
console.log(zeros(5), 1);
console.log(zeros(6), 1);
console.log(zeros(30), 7);
console.log(zeros(60), 14);
console.log(zeros(1000), 249); // missing 9 zeros?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: What was your leading idea to write the ```zeros``` function as such? what does "extraZeros stands for" and what is the logic behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that the amount of zeros increases from 0! for every 5 positive increments, but also increases 1 zero for every 25 increments.

You're right, but read this sentence again. Do you see the pattern?

It'll also increase a zero for every 125 and 625 increments, etc. You need to generalize based on powers of 5.

```js
const zeros = (n) => {
  let power = 1;
  let totalZeros = 0;
  while (n > 5 ** power) {
    totalZeros += Math.floor(n / (5 ** power));
    power++;
  }
  return totalZeros;
};
console.log(zeros(0), 0);
console.log(zeros(5), 1);
console.log(zeros(6), 1);
console.log(zeros(30), 7);
console.log(zeros(60), 14);
console.log(zeros(1000), 249);
```

Another way of writing it, from Patrick Roberts:

```js
const zeros = (n) => {
  let totalZeros = 0;
  for (let power = 5; power < n; power *= 5) {
    totalZeros += Math.floor(n / power);
  }
  return totalZeros;
};
console.log(zeros(0), 0);
console.log(zeros(5), 1);
console.log(zeros(6), 1);
console.log(zeros(30), 7);
console.log(zeros(60), 14);
console.log(zeros(1000), 249);
```

Comment: ahhh, it increases by a power, very well, Thank you!

Comment: `let totalZeros = 0; for (let power = 5; power < n; power *= 5) { totalZeros += Math.floor(n / power); } return totalZeros;` also works and might be a bit more readable.